# Is it possible to use Qooxdoo Native App on Stanalone App?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have my code that has been created on StandAlone application.
I want to use some class that generated from Native application.
but I don't know how to do it next.

Assume that i have my standalone class like this:

```
myWin = new qx.ui.window.Window();
```

and i have this class:

```
qx.Class.define("myapp.MyNative",
{
   extend : application.Native,
   members:{    
       ...........
  }
});
```

How can I use this class on myWin instance?
Or it may be:

```
mywin.add(new myapp.MyNative());
```

Please be suggested me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm you want to use a qooxdoo app inside a qooxdoo app ... that seems odd, I don't think it will work. if you want to use native javascript, css, html code, you can do this directly:

```js
var myWidget = new qx.ui.core.Widget();

myWidget.addListenerOnce('appear',function(e){

   var el = myWidget.getContentElement().getDomElement();
   /// do stuff to the element

},this);
```

to get native access to the dom element inside a qooxdoo widget.

Note that you can only grab the dom element once the widget has been rendered, so you have to use an `appear` event handler for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tobi.  Actually I am just want to use the animation ablity of qooxdoo native app on the standalone app. Do you have any suggestion more?

Comment: You can use animation inside a normal qooxdoo app ... look at the demo browser there are a bunch of examples ...

Comment: Thanks you again and again Tobi. I already have my solution from your guide and has been tested and it's work fine. It very usefully for qooxdoo beginner like me and hopefully for anyone who looking for the best javascript framework in the present time.